# Jenkins npm build fails to unzip a package on Windows slave

Tags: node.js, batch-file, jenkins, npm

I have added a windows slave to do npm build, in my package.json i have a step in which it performs "unzip pack.zip".

When i do npm build directly on the box it does everything successfully but when it gets done using Jenkins job, it fails to unzip the file i.e pack.zip

The file even gets extracted properly using tools like Unzip, Winrar and 7z etc.

I wrote the bat file to do npm build. when i ran it using cmd it worked without any issue but when i executed the same bat file from jenkins, it failed in the same extraction step.

Added log below:

```
  inflating: saui-client/node_modules/sig-quote/node_modules/sig-core/node_modules/underscore/underscore-min.map  
error:  expected central file header signature not found (file #73741).
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
  inflating: saui-client/node_modules/sig-quote/node_modules/sig-core/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js  
D:\jenkins\workspace\BUILD>exit 3 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Thanks for the log - what is the size of the zip you're trying to unzip and what is the format?

Comment: Listen - it's probably your unzip doesn't support Zip64 format, if that is the case make sure Jenkins slave is using the right version of UnZip, which OS are we talking about?

Comment: Hey, the file size is ~700mb, its a .zip file. Slave OS is Windows Server 2012.
I did mentioned the absolute path of the unzip utility using which i am able to extract the zip directly and using bat file but fails only when asked from jenkins. even fails when i execute the same bat file from jenkins.

Comment: to give you more idea. if i run **~/unzip pack.zip** from cmd, it works.
but when i put the same on Jenkins' "Execute batch" block, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind without the log is that you set your slave environment after connecting it to Jenkins - maybe even installed NodeJS after connecting it - meaning the session you have on your computer is not the same as was loaded when Jenkins was connected to it. The simple solution is to disconnect the slave and reconnect it with the new environment so the session will have all it needs to run. When you will have the log I will update my answer.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey @Dvir669 , Added log above.